# Comment peut-on éviter la réutilisation de l'adjectif « différent » et l'allitération en « d » dans cette phrase ?

Tags: grammaire, formulation

Je suis en train d'écrire un petit résumé sur le livre *Le Petit Prince*. Mais je ne suis pas sûr de la manière dont je peux reformuler cette phrase:

> Tout au long de son voyage, le petit prince rencontre des personnes différentes sur des planètes différentes.

Est-ce qu'il y a une façon de faire cette phrase qui semble plus naturelle ?  Spécifiquement l'usage de deux « différentes », et la cacophonie  (c'est mon impression) causée par la quantité de mots qui commencent par « d ».

Comment: Pourquoi crois-tu que cette phrase n'est pas naturelle ? Quel est le point particulier qui pourrait probablement être améliorer selon toi ? La correction de texte est hors-sujet sur ce site si tu ne précises pas le point particulier qui te pose problème.

Comment: Est-ce la double utilisation de « différentes » que tu veux éviter ? Si oui, merci de bien vouloir changer le titre de la question pour indiquer que c'est de ça qu'il s'agit.

Comment: J'ai modifié ma question, je suis désolé. J'ai cru que la cacophonie était évidente pour d'autres personnes aussi.

Comment: Ta phrase ne fonctionnerait probablement pas dans tous les contextes, mais en l’occurrence elle convient très bien. À mon goût, mieux que les réponses suggérées ci-dessous, qui s’éloignent plus stylistiquement de l’écriture du Petit Prince (enfin, de la vague idée que j’en ai encore en mémoire).

Comment: @Édouard merci pour ta réponse, donc, qu'est-ce que je dois faire s'il n'y a pas une bon réponse pour choisir comme la meilleur? J'ai décidé laisser la phrase comme ça puisque il n'y a pas de cacophonie apparemment.

Answer (score 2):

Pourquoi pas :

> Au long de son voyage, le petit prince rencontre plusieurs / de nombreuses personnes sur différentes planètes.

Le contexte de la phrase rend relativement immédiat que des personnes rencontrées sur des planètes distinctes sont sans doute elles-mêmes différentes. Les autres modifications que j'ai introduites dans la phrase me semblent la rendre plus naturelle. "De nombreuses" sonne mieux que "plusieurs", mais je ne pense pas qu'on puisse considérer que les rencontres du petit prince sont vraiment "nombreuses". Cela reste sans doute à améliorer.

Answer (score 0):

> Au cours de son périple sur différentes planètes le petit prince rencontre une galerie cosmopolite de personnages.

Le petit prince rencontre des personnages, comme Ulysse, qui retournant dans son île Ithaque, rencontre des héros et des dieux.